# The number of integer triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+b\cos(2x)+c\sin^2x=0$ for all $x$

Tags: trigonometry

The number of integer triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that 
$$a+b\cos(2x)+c\sin^2x=0\quad\text{for all $x$}$$ is

- (A) $0$
- (B) $1$
- (C) $3$
- (D) infinitely many

I tried to break $\cos 2x$ and write it in sine form, but got confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\cos{2x} = 1-2\sin^2{x}$.

Comment: I tried it but could not proceed further.

Comment: What is the simplified form of the equation that you obtained? It should be an expression with only constants and sin squared terms.

Comment: sin^2(x)=(a+b)/2b-c

Comment: Okay good, another way of writing that is
$$
[a+b] + [-2b+c]\sin^2{x} = 0
$$
This should be always equal to zero, regardless of the value of $\sin^2{x}$. Do you know what this implies for the expressions in the brackets?

Comment: Expressions in brackets should be equal to zero?0

Comment: That is correct. Now we have the pair of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
a &+ b & &= 0 \\
   & -2b& +c&= 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
How many solutions does this have?

Comment: c=2b; a=-b so the triplet is (-b,b,2b). Since b can be any real no. So there are infinite triplets possible. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct :) If you feel like my answers were helpful, please upvote my answer.

Comment: I liked your way of solving. You just gave hints and I solved it☺

Comment: But I am allowed to ask only two questions. why?

Comment: Only two questions? Where is such a restriction?

Comment: I don't know. I am new to it. They say that my way of asking question is not right etc and say that 'You should do your homework problem yourselves.

Comment: So it's a limitation in Math StackExchange? I guess it's there to reduce spamming, etc. So you just need to ask good questions. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok It was nice to talk with you. Thanks

Comment: I am unable to develop a firm grip on topics like Probability, Binomial Theorem. Any book you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76887/discussion-between-amit-aniket-and-matti-p).